# Javascript inside of Javascript Popups

Tags: javascript

I'm using the alert function to create a popup and I was wondering if there was a way to stick script in the popup. For example, I want to make a Google ad popup. My thoughts for it would be that the popup, instead of displaying text, would display a function. The function it'd use, 'displayAd()' for example, would just be run in the popup. Here is my code I'm thinking of.

```
<script>

function displayAd()
{
//My Google adsense code
}

function init()//Will occur on page load.
{
alert(displayAd());
}
</script>
```

I don't believe that'll work, but I'd like input. Thanks.

Comment: Have you gone ahead and tried running the code to see what happens?

Comment: `alert()` will convert everything you give it to a string, and is not meant to display anything other than text.

Comment: Believe me you don't want to put Google ads on pop-up because it is violate Google Adsense's TOS and you will get ban from that...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is much easier to simply create a div that will be in the center of the page, with the content of the AD.

Here I also added a div that will make the whole page fade except the AD.

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="showAD();">   //This will show the AD as soon as the page loads

    <div id="fade">     //The fading out of the page div

    <div id="AD">           //This div is for your AD
    //GOOGLE ADSENSE CODE
    </div>
    <br>
    <button onClick="closeAD();">Close</button>     //A button to close the AD

    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#fade{
    width: 100%:
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

#AD{
    width: #whatever suits you#;
    height: #whatever suits you#;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function displayAD(){
    document.getElementById("fade").style.display = block;
    document.getElementById("AD").style.display = block;
    }

function closeAD(){
    document.getElementById("fade").style.display = none;
    document.getElementById("AD").style.display = none;
    }
```

Comment: Why #div? What difference does that make compared to div.one?